# comparing 65 possible scores with 4225 possible combinations to come up with 4 possible answers

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

```
d28 = blue team score
f28 = red team score
```

a score has 65 possible outcomes (0-16 in .25 increments) like so:

> 0,    0.25,   0.5,    0.75,   1,  1.25,   1.5,    1.75,   2,  2.25,   2.5,    2.75,   3,  3.25,   3.5,    3.75,   4,  4.25,   4.5,    4.75,   5,  5.25,   5.5,    5.75,   6,  6.25,   6.5,    6.75,   7,  7.25,   7.5,    7.75,   8,  8.25,   8.5,    8.75,   9,  9.25,   9.5,    9.75,   10, 10.25,  10.5,   10.75,  11, 11.25,  11.5,   11.75,  12, 12.25,  12.5,   12.75,  13, 13.25,  13.5,   13.75,  14, 14.25,  14.5,   14.75,  15, 15.25,  15.5,   15.75 and   16

What I would like to do is compare every possible combination between the **blue team score** and **red team score**, and based on the combination, the formula will display **4 possible placeholder texts:** `"0-2", "2-0", "2-1" and "1-2"`

0 being the lowest score and 16 being the highest score out of the 65 possible scores. The place holder texts will show based on this:

> if blue team score anything between 16 - 12 and red team anything
>   between 4 - 0, answer is "2 - 0"
>
> if red team score anything between 16 - 12 and blue team anything
>   between 4 - 0, answer is "0 - 2"
>
> if blue team score anything between 12 - 8 and red team anything
>   between 8 - 4, answer is "2 - 1"
>
> if red team score anything between 12 - 8 and blue team anything
>   between 8 - 4, answer is "1 - 2"

So that would mean 4,225 possible combinations with only 4 placeholder texts between those combinations based on above.

This may help you visually, I've labeled the cell "HELP" where i need the placeholder text to show.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g7FFkbH2ldNRZVRHob3P-aFEI39Cbb2vQC0vGKCkGl0/pubhtml?widget=true&headers=false

in this example the blue team has a final score of 5.25 and the red team has a final score of 5. So it should display the placeholder text "2 - 1".

Finally, the place holder text background will fade between green to red based on how far the final scores are away from each other.

Example:

```
16 vs 8 = "2 - 1" (Green background)
12 vs 8 = "2 - 1" (brown, or whatever color is produced in the fade)
 9 vs 8 = "2 - 1" (Red background)
```

Comment: What are the rules for determining which of the 4 possible answers applies?

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to compute the answer for each of the 4225 possible combinations so that you can look up the answer from the list of 4225. Is this so that you can provide a data source for another system? Or can we just have  a formula that can be used in the HELP cell? (which would also be usable for calculating the 4225 answers)

Comment: Just a formula within the help cell is what I'm looking for, unless there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Based on those rules here is a formula

=IF(AND(Team1>=12,Team2<=4),"2-0",IF(AND(Team2>=12,Team1<=4),"0-2",IF(AND(Team1>=8,AND(Team2<=8,Team2>=4)),"1-2",IF(AND(Team2>=8,AND(Team1<=8,Team1>=4)),"1-2", "Not Defined"))))

Note if they both score 5 there is no rule defined. I have used a named reference so that this is more readable

You should be able to extend it as you fill out more of the missing rules